# how to install framework SDK(.NETCore, version=v5)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 Community for universal app development, but when ever I create a new project and select the universal app under windows the error pops up saying:

> "One or more projects requires a framework SDK(.NETCore v=5.00) that
>   is either not installed or is included as part of a future update to
>   visual studio"

In that error box there is a hyperlink mentioned to download the update but it goes right to the Microsoft website's home page.

I read some where to install the .NETCore via `nuget package manager` console. I have done that it was successful, but again whenever I create a new project it says to install the `Framework SDk(.NETCore v5)`.

I haven't found any solution on this particular error but their were some tutorials to install the .NETCore but they didn't helped me out.

Kindly tell me how to get rid of this, I have wasted almost my 5 days trying to fix this issue.

Comment: Now the same error box says "one or more project require a platform SDK(UAP, version=10.0.0.0) that is either not installed or is included as a part of a future update"

Answer (score 2):

i actually fixed that issue by First Modifying the setup of vs and their unchecking the Window Universal App development option. it means uninstalling the universal Window App development from visual studio then again modifying the setup i re checked the universal window App development option and update it. that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the "Tools and Windows SDK."

[image]

Comment: i have only found 1 option under universal windows App Development tools that is "tools (1.1.1) and windows  SDK (10.0.10240)" which is ticked and installed.