# Can't create UWP - Microsoft .NET Core 5.0.0

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Every time I try to create a UWP blank app I get an error about a Microsoft .NET Core 5.0.0 update required for Visual Studio, but I have already installed it.

[image: Visual Studio update required]

Comment: Does this error occur in Visual Studio 2019 ?

Comment: I have the same problem with VS 2017 and VS 2019

Comment: Try reinstalling Visual Studio and making sure you include the Universal Windows Platform workload in the installer

Comment: I just did, but I still get the same message

Comment: Please refer this [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33314873/7254781).

Comment: I tried it, still doesn't work.

Comment: Could your share the screenshot about Visual studio installation details where in the Visual studio installer ?

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: Please open universal windows platform development option.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted my PC and re-installed everything and now it works fine!